UK Entry clearance dates
Three of my dependents are going to join me in the UK, but the problem is that two of the have entry clearance dates that are valid untill December 18, 2024 while the third one's entry clearance starts on December 21 and is a child, so can not travel alone. The question now is how these dates can be aligned once entry clearance is issued. Do I need to apply again, or what?

Note: children can travel "alone", or better airlines will care about it, but you should check and set it up in advance. -- But: call the issuer authority and ask. I think they can fix it

@GiacomoCatenazzi Often the visa will say "only valid when accompanied" by some adult. I would not take it as a given, especially for those who need visas.

What travel dates did you request in the applications? Did you cross-reference the child’s application to the others? How old is the child? Does their visa specify the accompanying adult by name?

There's also the option of the adult(s) entering, obtaining their BRPs, then shuttling back to accompany the kid. Depends on OP's situation whether this makes sense.
